# django form request post not loading data

Tags: django, post, django-forms

I have am trying to load submitted data into a `Form` instance, `request.POST` has valid value but form does not.

```py
class ArticleCreateForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=255, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'off'}), label='')
    tagging = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'off'}), label='')
    towhere = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False) # default to unchecked, save

    class Meta:
        fields = ['title', 'tagging', 'towhere']

    def clean_title(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['title']
        if len(data) < 3:
            raise ValidationError('Title is too short')

    def clean_tagging(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['tagging']
        if len(data) == 0 or data is None:
            raise ValidationError('Please add at least one tag')
```

```py
@login_required
def articleChangeView(request, pk):
    try:
        article = Article.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if article.author != request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            form = forms.ArticleCreateForm(request.POST)
            print('--------')
            print(request.POST)
            print(form.cleaned_data)
```

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['gm0ODMFud35nhHlPdBr3IHVZXgtiDQV8zGPsscGWzcpylNVd0fnray7iodJvBWyb'], 'title': ['Title'], 'tagging': ['jquery']}>
{'title': None, 'tagging': None, 'towhere': ''}
```

I wonder why this happens, I will be so glad if you can give me a hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first should call [**`form.is_valid()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

@login_required
def articleChangeView(request, pk):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk, author=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ArticleCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('--------')
            print(request.POST)
            print(form.cleaned_data)
```

The `clean` methods of your `clean_fieldname`s should also return the cleaned value, so:

```
class ArticleCreateForm(forms.Form):
    # …

    def clean_title(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['title']
        if len(data) < 3:
            raise ValidationError('Title is too short')
        return data

    def clean_tagging(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['tagging']
        if not data:
            raise ValidationError('Please add at least one tag')
        return data
```

Comment: cheers, and I just noticed I must [return data in `clean_<fieldname>`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/)

Comment: @Weilory: ah yes. updated!